# Comment « appréhender » a-t-il glissé sémantiquement pour signifier « redouter, craindre » ?

Tags: étymologie, latin

*Appréhender* a trois sens :

D'abord « *prendre, saisir, attraper* » qui est le plus fidèle à son étymologie (du latin *apprehendere* de même sens).

Ensuite « *comprendre, saisir par l'esprit* », qui se comprend aussi assez bien. C'est simplement « saisir » au sens figuré, appliqué à une idée plutôt qu'à une chose physique.

Enfin, le dernier sens est « redouter, craindre », j'ai du mal à l'expliquer. D'où vient-il?

Les [sources](https://www.orthodidacte.com/videos-francais/decortiquons-le-mot-apprehender/) que j'ai pu trouver sur le sujet soulignent souvent le lien de parenté avec *apprendre*, qui partage l'origine, mais ne disent rien sur ce dernier sens.

Comment: Une seule explication, la peur du péché qui consiste a manger le fruit défendu de l'arbre de la connaissance du bien et du mal…Aujourd'hui, plusieurs interprétations […] de la Genèse concernant l'arbre de la connaissance du bien et du mal sont possibles. L'une d'elles est que l'arbre symbolise le savoir illimité qui n'appartient qu'à Dieu, […] L'arbre de la connaissance du bien et du mal symboliserait donc un désir profond de l'être humain : celui […]d'être en mesure de connaître tout […} https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbre_de_la_connaissance_du_bien_et_du_mal

Comment: conjecture amusante …

Comment: Pour redouter ou s'inquiéter des conséquences d'un acte, il faut d'abord les comprendre.

Comment: @Simon Le [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/appr%C3%A9hender) confirme ton approche : « comprendre, saisir »; d'où après évolution « prévoir, considérer comme étant à craindre; craindre »

Comment: Similar question for English: apprehend, apprehension... dunno whether the answer is similar.

Answer (score 1):

C'est aussi l'explication proposée par le dictionnaire Littré : *Appréhender signifie proprement saisir des mains, puis saisir de l'esprit, puis prévoir, et, par le passage de la prévision à la crainte, redouter*